# C++ equivalent of this java syntax

Tags: c++

In Java if we have this code:

```
class myClass{

   int timer;
   public myClass(int timer){
      this.timer = timer;
   }

   //rest of class
}
```

so now, i want to know what is the equivalent of this statement:

```
this.timer = timer;
```

or i am bound to use a different variable name in C++?

Thank you,

Comment: What about... learning *some* C++?

Comment: maybe this->timer = timer; Though I would suggest using a different variable name for the function input variable.

Comment: that's my point, i can use a different variable name, but just wanted to know is this a routine practice to always use different name or for elgancy of code can i use the this delimiter form???

Comment: As Abhishek Bansal said, `this->timer = timer;` will fulfill the same purpose.

Comment: You would use the constructor initialization list: `myClass(int timer) : timer(timer) {}`. If you find yourself using `this` a lot you have taken a wrong turn somewhere.

Comment: Removing `[java]` as the answer won't have anything to do with Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a different variable name. You can use member initialization:

MyClass::MyClass(int timer) : timer(timer) {}

The timer outside the parentheses is the member variable; the one inside is the argument that was passed in to the constructor.